# ASP.NET 3.5 Multiple Role Providers

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 application that I recently extended with multiple membership and role providers to "attach" a second application within this application.  I do not have direct access to the IIS configuration, so I can't break this off into a separate application directory.

That said, I have successfully separated the logins; however, after I login, I am able to verify the groups the user belongs to through custom role routines, and I am capable of having identical usernames with different passwords for both "applications."

The problem that I am running into is when I create a user with an identical username to the other membership (which uses web.config roles on directories), I am able to switch URLs manually to the other application, and it picks up the username, and loads the roles for that application.  Obviously, this is bad, as it allows a user to create a username of someone who has access to the other application, and cross into the other application with the roles of the other user.

How can I mitigate this?  If I am limited to one application to work with, with multiple role and membership providers, and the auth cookie stores the username that is apparently transferable, is there anything I can do?

I realize the situation is not ideal, but these are the imposed limitations at the moment.

Example Authentication (upon validation):

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(usr.UserName, false);
```

This cookie needs to be based on the user token I suspect, rather than UserName in order to separate the two providers?  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps not the answer I'd prefer to go with, but I was able to separate the two by having one application use the username for the auth cookie, and the other use the ProviderUserKey (guid).  This way the auth cookie would not be recognized from one "application" to the other.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.ProviderUserKey.ToString(), false);
```

This required me to handle things a little oddly, but it simply came down to adding some extension methods, and handling a lot of membership utilities through my own class (which I was doing anyhow).

ex. Extension Method:

```
public static string GetUserName(this IPrincipal ip)
{
    return MNMember.MNMembership.GetUser(new Guid(ip.Identity.Name), false).UserName;
}
```

Where MNMember is a static class, MNMembership is returning the secondary membership provider, and GetUser is the standard function of membership providers.

```
var validRoles = new List<string>() { "MNExpired", "MNAdmins", "MNUsers" };
            var isValidRole = validRoles.Intersect(uroles).Any();
            if (isValidRole)
            {
                var userIsAdmin = uroles.Contains("MNAdmins");
                if (isAdmin && !userIsAdmin)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("/MNLogin.aspx");
                }
                else if (!userIsAdmin && !uroles.Contains("MNUsers"))
                {
                    Response.Redirect("/MNLogin.aspx");
                }...
```

Where isAdmin is checking to see if a subdirectory shows up in the path.

Seems hacky, but also seems to work.

Edit:Now that I'm not using the username as the token, I should be able to go back to using the web.config for directory security, which means the master page hack should be able to be removed. (theoretically?)

Edit 2:Nope - asp.net uses the username auth cookie to resolve the roles specified in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the applicationName attribute in your membership connection string?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Yes, they are separated by application name.  There are two role providers with different application names, and two membership providers with different application names (matching role to membership, of course).